# Passing of parameters in a v-for loop into a bootstrap modal and outputting it

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to pass an index number (loanRequest[6][index]) which is in a v-for loop into a bootstrap modal which has a texbox and then sending an object (obj) which contains both the index number and the content of the texbox (reason) to my backend API.

Here's my Vuejs code:

```js
<tr v-for="(n,index) in loanRequest[1]">
    <td v-for="">{{loanRequest[0][index]}}</td>
    <td v-for="">{{loanRequest[7].staff_name}}</td>
    <td v-for="">{{loanRequest[1][index]}}</td>
    <td v-for="">{{loanRequest[2][index]}}</td>
    <td v-for="">{{loanRequest[3][index]}}</td>
    <td v-for="">{{loanRequest[4][index]}}</td>
    <td v-for="">{{loanRequest[5][index].created_at}}</td>
    <td><a  :href="'http://localhost:8080/loans/details/'+loanRequest[6][index]"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">view details</button></a></td>
    <td><a ><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#approve" @click="approveUpdate(loanRequest[6][index])">Approve</button></a>
     <a ><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#reject" @click="clearbox(loanRequest[6][index])">Reject</button></a>
    </td>
    <br><br>
   </tr>
        
  </table>

  <!-- Modal reject -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="reject" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Loan Rejection</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Are you sure you want to reject this loan request?</p>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Reason: </label>
              <input v-model="reason" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your reason">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" v-show="reason" @click="clearbox">Reject</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
 export default {
  data () {
   return {
    loanRequest: '',
                reason: ''
   }
  },
      methods: {
      clearbox (index){
        var obj = {
          "id": index,
          "reason": this.reason
        };
        console.log(obj);
        this.reason = null;
      }
    }
 }
</script>
```

Presently with my above code, I am getting 2 objects with the first one conataining the index number and the second object containing the textbox content.
How can I merge them together to get one object (obj) which contains both the index number and the modal textbox content? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move you modal dialog to additional component, then pass your index as a props.